# How to "reshape" into square matrix for numpy.linalg.solve()?

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the intersection of lines $y=a_1x+b_1$ and $y=a_2x+b_2$ using `numpy.linalg.solve()`. What I can't get my head around is how to correctly make $A$ a square matrix for `solve()` to work. I'm familiar with solving linear equation systems, but there's something here I don't get.

What I'd like to do is:

```py
def meeting_lines(a1, b1, a2, b2):
    a = np.array([[a1], [a2]])
    b = np.array([b1, b2])
    return np.linalg.solve(a, b)

def main():
    a1=1
    b1=4
    a2=3
    b2=2

    y, x = meeting_lines(a1, b1, a2, b2)
```

Where I expect $y=-3$ and $x=1$. However, this fails with `numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square`.

Thank you very much for your help, trying to figure this out has messed up my day already!

Comment: NB: I must use `numpy.linalg.solve()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should formulate your lines as follows to have $(x, y)$ as unknowns:
$$\begin{align}
\left.\begin{matrix}
a_1x-y=-b_1\\
a_2x-y=-b_2
\end{matrix}\right\}
\rightarrow
\overbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
 a_1& -1\\ 
 a_2& -1
\end{bmatrix}
}^{\boldsymbol{a}}
\overbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
 x\\ 
 y
\end{bmatrix}
}^{\boldsymbol{x}}
=
\overbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
 -b_1\\ 
 -b_2
\end{bmatrix}
}^{\boldsymbol{b}}
\end{align}$$
Therefore, the code should be:

```
import numpy as np

def meeting_lines(a1, b1, a2, b2):
    a = np.array([[a1, -1], [a2, -1]])
    b = np.array([-b1, -b2])
    return np.linalg.solve(a, b)

a1=1
b1=4
a2=3
b2=2
x, y = meeting_lines(a1, b1, a2, b2)
print(x, y)
```

which outputs:

```
1.0 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid [numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix](https://www.statology.org/python-numpy-linalg-singular-matrix/) (determinant=0) when using other vars - Esmailian's codelines can be corrected with *try: .. except: ..* Error_handler - something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def meeting_lines(arr):
##    print("arr:\n",arr)
    a1, b1, a2, b2 = arr
    try:
        a = np.array([[a1, -1], [a2, -1]])
        b = np.array([-b1, -b2])
        res= np.linalg.solve(a, b)
    except: 
        # 1. The determinant of a singular matrix (for squared matrices) is zero. A non-invertible matrix is referred to as singular matrix 
        # 2. "never explicitly invert matrix on a computer because of inaccuracy in floating point representation error" - use linalg pckg with Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms (BLAS)
        # 3. in scipy to deal with floats can use: scipy.allclose(det, 0)

        res = np.Inf # perfect correlation (=1)
    return res

# USED for a1, b1, a2, b2 packed into array
print(meeting_lines(np.array([3., 1., 3., 7.], dtype=float)))
```